# np.random.choice not producing expected histogram

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to generate `random normally distributed` numbers between 1 and 0, but as the `mean` moves closer to 1 or 0, the right or left side respectively becomes "squished".

After modifying the normal distribution and playing around with sliders in geogebra, I came up with the following:

[image: equation]

[image: mu=0.5, stddev = 0.8]

[image: mu=0.75, stddev = 0.8]

Next I needed to create a method in `python` which would generate random samples that would be distributed according to this PDF.

Originally I thought the only way to do this was to try and derive a new equation for generating random numbers as seen in the `Box-Muller` proof (which I got by following along with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvneCLZ3dLk) tutorial).

However, I thought there might be an easier way to do this by using the `numpy` library's `np.random.choice()` method.

After all, I should be able to integrate the PDF at a very small step size and get the various probabilities for said steps (approximately of course).

So with that I wrote the following script:

```
# Standard libs
import math

# Third party libs
import numpy as np

from alive_progress import alive_bar
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class RandomNumberGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def clamped_normal_distribution(self, mu: float, 
            stddev: float, x: float):
        """ Computes a value from the clamped normal distribution """
        divideByZeroAvoider = 1e-5
        if x < 0 or x > 1:
            return 0
        elif x >= 0 and x <= mu:
            return math.exp(-0.5*( (x - mu) / (stddev)  )**2 \
                    * (1/(x**2 + divideByZeroAvoider)))
        elif x <= 1 and x > mu:
            return math.exp(-0.5*( (x - mu) / (stddev)  )**2 \
                    * (1/((1-x)**2 + divideByZeroAvoider))) 
        else:
            print("This shouldn't happen!: {}".format(x))
            return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rng = RandomNumberGenerator()

    mu = 0.7
    stddev = 1
    stepSize = 1e-3
    x = np.linspace(stepSize,1, int(1/stepSize) - 1)

    # Determine the total area under the curve
    samples = []
    print("Generating samples...")
    with alive_bar(len(x.tolist())) as bar:
        for i in x:
            samples.append(rng.clamped_normal_distribution(
                    mu, stddev, i))
            bar()

    area = np.trapz(samples, dx=stepSize)
    print("Area = {}".format(area))

    # Determine the probability of x falling in a specific interval
    probabilities = []

    print("Generating probabilties...")
    with alive_bar(len(x.tolist())) as bar:
        for i in x:
            lead = rng.clamped_normal_distribution(mu, 
                    stddev, i)
            lag = rng.clamped_normal_distribution(mu, 
                    stddev, i - stepSize)
            probability = np.trapz(
                    np.array([lag, lead]), 
                    dx=stepSize)
            
            # Divide by the area because this isn't a standard normal
            probabilities.append(probability / area)
            bar()
    
    # Should be approximately 1
    print("Probability: {}".format(sum(probabilities)))

    plt.plot(x, probabilities)
    plt.show()

    y = []
    print("Performing distribution test...")
    testSize = int(10e3)
    with alive_bar(testSize) as bar:
        for _ in range(testSize):
            randSamp = np.random.choice(samples, p=probabilities)
            y.append(randSamp)
            bar()

    plt.hist(y,300)
    plt.show()
```

The first plot of the probabilities against the linearly spaced samples looks promising, giving me the following graph:

[image]

However, if we use these samples as choices with given probabilities, we get the following histogram:

[image]

I have no idea why this isn't working correctly.

I've tried other (smaller) examples like the ones listed on the [numpy website](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html), and they produce histograms of the according to the given probabilities array.

I'd really appreciate some advice/intuition if at all possible :).

Comment: A normal distribution is not normally bounded.   Are you sure you don't want a [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)?

Comment: That is true, I could use a beta distribution for this, however I still want to investigate whether a method such as this can be used to solve this problem.

In future I might have odd PDFs that I'm required to randomly sample from, hence if a method such as np.random.choice could be made to work in the way I've eluded to above, then we'd have a means to generate random samples from any given PDF (which would be awesome!).

Comment: After a quick look, I suspect there is a problem with the first argument in the call `np.random.choice(samples, p=probabilities)`.  Shouldn't that be `x`, not `samples`?

Comment: @Warren Weckesser, that did it, makes sense too, will post an answer soon (unless you want to of course).

Comment: @Despicable_B, I added a short answer.

Comment: Cheers @Warren Weckesser, I'll add some figures to confirm that it works in a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with the first argument in the call `np.random.choice(samples, p=probabilities)`.  The first argument should be `x`, not `samples`.

**ADDITION BY AUTHOR:**

The reason for this is the `samples` are the values of the curve (i.e. the y-axis and NOT the x-axis).

Thus the values with the highest probabilities (i.e. the samples around the mean) all have a value of ~1, which is why we see such a massive spike around the value 1.

Changing this to `x` gives us the following graphs (for `10e3` samples):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Working as expected, very nice.